# After overriding the Clean method in AuthenticationForm, authenticate returns None, and does not handle any errors

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

friend.

There was a need to override the `Сlean` method in `AuthenticationForm` to further check for the presence of an attribute before the user can log in.

Forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm as BaseAuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from inc.models import Account, UserProfile, Counter

class AuthenticationForm(BaseAuthenticationForm):

    def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    user = User.objects.filter(username = username).first()
    if user != None:
        print(user)
        if not user.is_superuser and not user.is_staff:
            account = Account.objects.filter(num_account = UserProfile.objects.filter(user__username = username).first().num_account).first()
            have_counter = Counter.objects.filter(num_account = account).all()
            if not have_counter:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Some text...')
    return self.cleaned_data
```

Views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from .forms import AuthenticationForm

def LogIn(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print(user)
        login(request, user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
else:
    form = AuthenticationForm()
return render(request, 'userprocessing/login.html', {'form': form})
```

The problem is as follows. When I try to register as a user who is in the database everything works as it should, but when I enter a non-existent login I throw out:

```
AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

which points to `login(request, user)`. The error is understandable, it can not login the user which does not return `user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)` (it returns `None`).

The question is why it does not handle the error, there must be a message check the username or password.

Perhaps I did not correctly redefine `Clean` method in `AuthenticationForm`?

**UPD:**

Traceback:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/login/?next=/

Django Version: 2.0.5
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'inc.apps.IncConfig',
 'main.apps.MainConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "...\views.py" in LogIn
  57.             login(request, user)

File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in login
  155.     request.session[SESSION_KEY] = user._meta.pk.value_to_string(user)

File "...\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in inner
  216.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /login/
Exception Value: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `clean` method, you are only raising an error in a case the user exists but is not a superuser neither a staff.

You should also raise an error when the user does not exist at all.

I would do it this way using try, except, else.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    username = cleaned_data.get('username')
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        raise forms.ValidationError('User does not exist...')
    else:
        print(user)
        if not user.is_superuser and not user.is_staff:
            account = Account.objects.filter(num_account=UserProfile.objects.filter(user__username=username).first().num_account).first()
            have_counter = Counter.objects.filter(num_account=account).all()
            if not have_counter:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Some text...')
    return cleaned_data
```

> PS. I did not check the logic of your clean method except for
>   whether the user exists or not.

Check Django's docs about validating forms. Also on why you should call super inside your overridden `clean()`.

- [Overriding the clean() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-modelform-clean-method)
- [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/)

Comment: I tried, but the error remained. As I understood, Clean's method works fine. The problem is that there is no call error in the authenticate. Maybe I'm redefining it incorrectly. Except errors did not happen.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Try it as-is and let me know. It should raise an error inside clean which will force form.is_valid() to return `False`

Comment: It works, thank you so much. Could you briefly explain or give a link to where to say what this means cleaned_data = super (). Clean ().

Comment: Added to the answer